# Show/hide child of user control in design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a custom user control which contains a textbox and two labels.  These labels will act as buttons - one to show a calendar and one to clear the textbox.

I have exposed two properties to control whether or not each of these labels is visible.  This works as expected in runtime.  However, when the user changes either of these properties - "ShowCalendar" and "ShowClear" - to false, I'd like the corresponding label control to be hidden in design time.  The Microsoft DateTimePicker achieves this exact same functionality with the "ShowCheckBox" property.  How would I go about implementing this functionality into my custom designer?

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: this is supported by the designer naturally, I hope your code at runtime **doesn't** explicitly set the `Visible` of your controls when the corresponding properties toggle.

Comment: @King King: You are correct.  This is supported natively by the designer. All I had to do was wire up a property to handle visibility of the child control and it works.  I was trying to make this too complicated using custom designers.